# DialogResult.OK as an integer in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an integer equivalent to `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`, instead of me having to reference the Windows forms library for 1 line of code?

So that I could write (for example):

```
if(form.ShowDialog() == 6)
```

instead of:

```
if(form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: Well what form are you using? The dialog result is to match up to the windows form form

Comment: ..I'm confused.. whats the issue then? You already need windows forms

Comment: In order to use `ShowDialog`, you must reference `System.Windows.Forms`. The assembly is already being referenced, so just add a using statement of `using System.Windows.Forms` and compare to `DialogResult.OK`.

Comment: I don't understand your point. You are already referencing the Windows.Form library because you are using a Form and calling ShowDialog

Comment: In your question you said "reference" but that usually means adding an assembly reference. Did you instead mean adding a "using" statement to bring the namespace into scope or fully qualifying it?

Comment: You won't win any coding awards by going back to those magic numbers.  You could just look it up yourself: `MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(DialogResult.OK).ToString());`  You can also just disregard the `System.Windows.Forms` part since you obviously already have the reference.  It would just be `form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK`

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have the reference. I create a new form object in a different class that does not reference `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: So why don't you want to reference it? What are you hoping to avoid by doing so?

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: I would avoid put gui objects inside of data classes.

Comment: @Sayse because I don't want to include the entire library for one check. -LarsTech the gui is not inside of my data class, rather my control class.

Comment: How do you avoid the library when you do `form.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @Adjit - I get the feeling you come from a background that doesn't use a compiled language... you wouldn't be doing the entire library

Comment: @Sayse false, my background is mostly in C, but in the process of dusting off a few cobwebs.

Comment: @LarsTech the library is being referenced by a different class.

Comment: `form.ShowDialog()` requires access to `System.Windows.Forms` just as `DialogResult` does. You save nothing at all, and since it is one line of code, they cant be in 2 different places

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is usually better to avoud casting between integers and enumeration constants.

IMO, the canonical form is the best:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
....
if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Anyway, if it is not desirable, you could consider making alias with [using alias directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).  Something like this:

```
using Res = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult;
....
if(form.ShowDialog() == Res.OK)
```

P.S. And yes, if you really want, you could cast:

```
if((int)form.ShowDialog() == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but more I hope to explain that you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

From [the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664764(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Using directives facilitate the use of namespaces and types defined in other namespaces. Using directives impact the name resolution process of namespace-or-type-names (Section 3.8) and simple-names (Section 7.5.2), but unlike declarations, using directives **do not contribute new members to the underlying declaration spaces of the compilation units or namespaces within which they are used.**

(Emphasis mine)

In other words, the using statement you would need doesn't actually hinder you in any way. You aren't fully including the whole package like you would be in a different language such as Python.

<sub>For the record, there is a better way of referencing a resource in python than the whole package but thats irrelevant</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at the values of that enumeration directly at http://referencesource.microsoft.com

Here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DialogResult.cs,489debd4e71ec9d7